# Google cloud function returning 204 status when accessing realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a website for testing purposes hosted via firebase, storing client information on a realtime database which needs to be accessed later. When I do this via a single html document with a script that accesses my reatime database I am able to find information successfuly, but when I copied and pasted that same logic into a cloud function it did not work. I have tried everything I can think of and now when I run the function it executes twice (I am not sure why). The first execution finishes with a http 204 status (no content found). The second execution returns http 500 internal service error. When I checked the logs on firebase it says the error was because "accounts.getValue() is not a function". I think what is happening is on the first execution the function is unable to locate accounts and it executes again without trying to find the accounts, which might be why it can't run accounts.getValue()

I guess my main question is why is my function unable to locate accounts?

geturl is the function I am having trouble with

The structure of my realtime database is 
database name

```
-accounts

  -some data

  -more data

  -more account data
-ActiveQRs
  -some data...
```

My index.js file for cloud functions is

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');

const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

var firebase = require("firebase");


var admin = require("firebase-admin");

require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/database");
//require("firebase/firestore");
//require("firebase/messaging");
require("firebase/functions");


var serviceAccount = require("./serviceKey.json");


// Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin 
//privileges
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com"
});

const displayqr = express();
const geturl = express();


displayqr.get('/displayqr', (request, response) => {
    console.log("response sent");
        response.send("testio/qrdisplay.html");
    });




 exports.displayqr = functions.https.onRequest(displayqr);



 exports.geturl = functions.https.onCall((email) => {

    const mail = email.toString();
    var result = "";
    result = result + mail;
       var accounts = 
admin.database().ref("livsuiteform/accounts");
       result = (accounts.getValue());
       accounts.orderByKey().on("value", function(snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
            if (data.child("Email").val() == mail) {
              var firstName = data.child("FirstName").val();
              var lastName = data.child("LastName").val();
              result = firstname;
              result = "if loop entered";
              } // end if
         //     return "name not found";
              }); // end for each
          }); // end order by
       return result; 
    });
```

Comment: PS I want this function to read database date when it is called from an external website not on database write or any other kind of event

Comment: Did you get snapshot data from firebase in console?

Comment: On the website console nothing shows up which makes since because the function is being run on the server, but on the firebase logs I haven't seen any of my message logs, I haven't been able to see console.log anywhere, thats why my result is a string, eventualy I want it to return a url but I have been returning my result and using it as a console for debugging

Comment: And no I haven't been able to see the snapshot data when I do result = snapshot.getValue();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; follow this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) on how to build and deploy callable functions for your mobile app.

There are multiple reasons for why your functions aren't working as you expect.

1. You are including the client-side version of Firebase (`var firebase = require("firebase");`). You shouldn't use or even require the client-side version. Instead just use Firebase Admin ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/)) to access any data. If you need certain user permissions when accessing the DB from the Admin SDK, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database) is a good example of how to achieve that (Scroll down to "You can still perform user-authorized changes...").
2. You have mixed different Admin SDK references. [`getValue()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(boolean)) is part of the Admin SDK for Java. You should use the JavaScript equivalent [`val()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#val). Also, in your code, `accounts` is a `Reference` and not a `DataSnapshot`.
3. You aren't returning your `Promise`'s. This can be a source of inconsistency in your function execution later [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50608964/cloud-function-http-request-with-multiple-batch-read-writes/50705199#50705199).
4. You aren't returning anything from your initial function. If you don't return anything, then nothing will get returned to your app. The solution is the same as 3's solution: return your `Promise`.
5. You shouldn't use [`on`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#on) in Firebase Functions. You should use [`once`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once). The difference is that `on` doesn't return a `Promise` while `once` does. It returns a function that is used to detach the listener.

I know this is a lot of bullet points and pointing out problems in your code, but I just didn't want give a shallow answer which resulted in you asking another question and waiting another ~2 hours (at the time of writing) for an answer.

I hope this helps!

#### Code

```
exports.geturl = functions.https.onCall((email) => {

  const mail = email.toString();
  var result = "";
  result = result + mail;
  var accounts = admin.database().ref("livsuiteform/accounts");
  return accounts.orderByKey().once("value")
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
        if (data.child("Email").val() == mail) {
          var firstName = data.child("FirstName").val();
          var lastName = data.child("LastName").val();
          result = firstName;
          result = "if loop entered";
        } // end if
        //     return "name not found";
      }); // end for each
      return result;
    }); // end order by
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan, that helped, I think I am still having a hard time with the promises, which lines of code require a promise and how can I return one? I replace on with once but my function still executes twice and takes around 2 seconds to run when it should be very quick

Comment: @DHolthaus I added some code that should get it running correctly. `geturl` should look similar to what is above. I'd suggest running through the tutorial I linked.

Comment: I think looks almost exactly like my code now but it still isn't retrieving information from the database and I am unsure why. Now when I call the function (right now I have my app logging the result of the function to the console) it returns the email used, meaning result = result + mail; worked but the other statements didn't. In the firebase logs now my function runs three times with each call, and the third call returns an error saying firstname is not defined.

Comment: I ran through the tutorial but it was mostly on the client side and I didn't see much about promises, could you tell me what you changed? the only change I can see is changing on to once and using .then

Comment: @DHolthaus I changed quite a bit. I returned a `Promise` by returning `accounts.orderByKey()...`. I fixed `firstname` not being the same as `firstName`. I removed the return at the end of the function `return result;`. If you copy/paste the code I provided, you should see that the result will be either the `email` or a `firstName`.

Comment: @DHolthaus to answer your issue of the function running multiple times; nothing inside the function `geturl` will cause it to re-execute. That issue is arising from your mobile app. In the tutorial I linked, it takes you through all the steps needed (and that I'm explaining) to build and deploy a simple callable function (with Promises).

Comment: Now my function is returning null, but I might be able to figure this out. Thanks for all your help, this was driving me crazy and I feel a lot better about it now